# Not able to show head-up notification popup

Tags: java, android, notifications

No popup style/ message is displayed like when I am clicking any button. I am using all conditions required for api less than 7.
I don't know the problem.

Here is the code for notification channel

```java
public class notificationExercise extends Application {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        notificationChannel();
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void notificationChannel(){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Utils.CHANNEL_ID, Utils.CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription(Utils.CHANNEL_Desc);
        NotificationManager managerCompat = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        managerCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

And the main activity code

```java
public void headsupnotification(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://github.com/girlscript/winter-of-contributing"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Utils.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(Utils.NOTI_TITLE)
                .setContentText(Utils.NOTI_DESC)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Visit to GWOC GitHub Repo", pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(Utils.NOTI_ID, Builder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Is your notification showing up or not?

Comment: Yes now its showing up

Comment: Is ur problem solved or not?